# How to efficiently perform union of two queries with and without group by

Tags: sql, hive, group-by, subquery, union

I have a query that performs a union between two select statements one that uses group by and another that doesn't. The problem is I'm selecting the same columns and using the same fucntions in both select statements. It feels Im duplicating the code and I wish to know if there's a better way to write this

I've tried to use the normal union function to two select statements, but both select statements use the same functions.
Is there a way to simplify the following query without duplication?

Example:

```
select 
sum(col1), sum(col2)....
from table

union

select sum(col1), sum(col2)...
from table
group by class
```

I require a table which is obtained by combining the result of the above.
The second query may have multiple categories and first query yields only one aggregated row
The objective is to compare the income and other details of the total population with one or more of categories within the population

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the [`WITH ROLLUP`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Enhanced+Aggregation%2C+Cube%2C+Grouping+and+Rollup) clause to your `GROUP BY` and it will add an aggregate row to the end of your output i.e.

```
SELECT SUM(col1), SUM(col2)...
FROM table
GROUP BY class WITH ROLLUP
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided the sample data to check, but one approach can be using `CASE WHEN` in `GROUP BY`.

Following `UNION`

```
SELECT Sum(col1) 
FROM   tablename 
WHERE  id <> 1 
UNION 
SELECT Sum(col1) 
FROM   tablename 
WHERE  id = 1 
GROUP  BY class
```

Can be written as following using `CASE`

```
SELECT Sum(col1) 
FROM   tablename 
GROUP  BY CASE 
            WHEN id = 1 THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
          END
```